# Are there any python modules to store passwords securely in .conf/.txt files?

Tags: python, pycrypto, python-keyring, pyjks

I am trying to read and write username and password in a secured manner. With my current implementation I am following [AES-CBC](https://www.floyd.ch/?p=293) encryption/decryption but storing the encrypted username the with random key in a config file is a security issue. I found an option that keystore is a better way of storing passwords. I have checked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790315/python-equivalent-of-javas-keystore) but the information is not clear to me. Another option that I found is the keyring, it is working fine in windows but on Linux , I am getting following error. I have checked for the possible solutions but couldn't find one.

```
python keyring-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keyring-test.py", line 3, in <module>
    keyring.set_password(service_name="demo-service",username="admin",password="test")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keyring/core.py", line 64, in set_password
    _keyring_backend.set_password(service_name, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keyring/backends/fail.py", line 23, in get_password
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: No recommended backend was available. Install the keyrings.alt package if you want to use the non-recommended backends. See README.rst for details.
```

Can someone suggest me any better solution or modules from python to store passwords securely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Equivalent of Java's 'Keystore'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790315/python-equivalent-of-javas-keystore). [Edit] your Question and show which *information* from the dup isn't clear to you.

Comment: @stovfl I have updated my question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html **secrets**

Comment: Unless it's your own passwords you want to store somewhere, I don't see any use for storing others passwords. But for that I'd use PGP instead :)

Comment: You have **no** backend installed, read [recommended keyring backends](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/#what-is-python-keyring-lib). Relevant [keyring-module-is-not-included-while-packaging-with-py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852259/keyring-module-is-not-included-while-packaging-with-py2exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My implementation whas this:
I made a random string and store it to a txt file then encrypt its bytes file under a key! I use two function that i have made which the `def encrypt_file` takes a file encrypt their bytes and returns an encrypted file and `def dencrypt_file` does the opposite .

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
import os
import pathlib

def encrypt_file(key,filein,fileout=None,IV=None):
    modes = [1,2,8,3,6,9,11,12,10,5]
    if os.path.isfile(filein):
        if IV == None:
            IV = 16 * b'\x00'
        else:
            IV = IV.encode("utf-8")
        if len(IV)==16:
            if fileout == None:
                fileout_path = pathlib.Path(filein).parent
                fileout_name = pathlib.Path(filein).name
            else:
                fileout_path = pathlib.Path(fileout).parent
                fileout_name = pathlib.Path(fileout).name
                print (fileout_path, fileout_name )
                if os.path.exists(fileout_path) == False:
                    print("Path Does Not Exists")
                    return

            encryptor = AES.new(hashlib.sha256(key.encode("utf-8")).digest(), 3, IV=IV)
            with open(filein,"rb") as f :
                f = f.read()
                encr_bytes = encryptor.encrypt(f)
                file = open(str(fileout_path)+"\\"+str(fileout_name)+".enc","wb")
                file.write(encr_bytes)
                file.close()
                del encryptor
        else:
            print ("IV must 16 bytes long")
            return
    else:
        print("No file path")
        return




def dencrypt_file(key,filein,fileout=None,IV=None,TXT = False):
    if os.path.isfile(filein):
        if IV == None:
            IV = 16 * b'\x00'
        else:
            IV = IV.encode("utf-8")
        if len(IV)==16:
            if fileout == None:
                fileout_path = pathlib.Path(filein).parent
                fileout_name = pathlib.Path(filein).name
                list_name = fileout_name.split(".")
            else:
                fileout_path = pathlib.Path(fileout).parent
                fileout_name = pathlib.Path(fileout).name
                list_name =  fileout_name.split(".")
                if os.path.exists(fileout_path) == False:
                    print("Path Does Not Exists")
                    return
            file_name = list_name[0] + "." + list_name[1]
            if os.path.isfile(str(fileout_path)+"\\"+str(file_name)):
                file_name = list_name[0] + "new" +"." + list_name[1]
                print(file_name, "OK")
            else:
                file_name = file_name
            final_path = str(fileout_path) + "\\" +  file_name
            encryptor = AES.new(hashlib.sha256(key.encode("utf-8")).digest(), 3, IV=IV)
            with open(filein,"rb") as f :
                if TXT == False:
                    file = open(final_path,"wb")
                    file.write(encryptor.decrypt(f.read()))
                    file.close()
                else:
                    return encryptor.decrypt(f.read()).decode("utf-8")
        else:
            print ("IV must 16 bytes long")
            return
    else:
        print("No file path")
return
```

The parameters are

- key : your secret key
- filein : the file that you want to encrypt
- fileout : the output file
- IV : the initialization Vector

Comment: And the `key` is stored **where**?

Comment: nowhere. The key you can provide ti with the input function. Afterwords the encrypt or decrypt function hash the value and decrypt or encrypt the file with the key. In any crypto - way somehow you have to provide a key to unlock something! So the key that unlocks the file is stored in your brain and the random big key that unlocks-locks something is encrypted under that key.